# Programmatically insert an equation editor 3.0 in Word 2010

Tags: c#, vsto, equation, word-2010

Using this code

```
        var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        Range rng = app.ActiveDocument.Range();
        rng.Text = "BD/DC = AB/AC ";

        rng = rng.OMaths.Add(rng);
        OMath objEq = rng.OMaths[1] ;
        objEq.BuildUp();
```

I can enter an equation into Word 2010 but it appears in the `new equation editor`.

I want to insert an equation in the older equation editor (`Equation Editor 3.0`). Is this possible in C# VSTO?

I can manually do it in `Word 2010` by going to `insert object --> Equation Editor 3.0` and then type out the equation but I would like to do this via c#.

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Range rng = app.ActiveDocument.Range();
object oClassType = "Equation.3";            
rng.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ref oClassType);
```

That inserts one, but I'm honestly not quite sure how to then manipulate it...

Comment: Wow! Many Thanks! Really that's a fine start. Now how to manipulate it?... Maybe ask another question on SO ;)

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729352/creating-an-equation-editor-3-0-equation-in-a-word-2003-document-using-a-marco this page and it suggests to try out MathTypeSDK. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Tried it but it asks for MT6.dll which is not present on the system. Is there any way to add equations to the equation editor 3.0 via C# vsto?

Comment: That may be the reason why they introduced the new equation editor, because they wanted to make it more friendly for VSTO.

Comment: Isn't there any kind of way to interface to Equation Editor 3.0, any interop lib etc??

Answer (score 1):

If you inserted an OLE object via AddOLEObject, the return value of AddOLEObject is a shape, whose OLEFormat property should get you the automation interface of the inseted object via its own Object property.

However, there is no type library shipped with MSEE 3.0, so you don't know the correct dispids , property names and method signatures. Since it is basically MathType Express licensed from Design Science, you might want to contact Design Science and ask you could license their modern product for your customers.